# Generates interrupt when a variable value changes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, interrupt

I have a large program that changes the value of a variable, say `Var`, incrementing or decrementing. At any time when `Var = 5` I want to execute a subroutine, say `Flag()`.

What is the "appropriate" way to implement this?

What I have in mind is this:

```
While True
    If Var = 5 then
        Flag()
    End If
End While
```

But it looked quite silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Sub or a Property, change your variable using it, that way you can check the value.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Var As Integer

    Private Sub updateVar(value As Integer)
        Var = value
        If Var = 5 Then
            MsgBox("Var = 5")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Neat. Didn't thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a property and whenever the setter changes call a function:

```
Public Class MyVarWrapper
    Private _i As Integer

    Public Property Var() As Integer
        Get
            Return _i
        End Get
        Set
            _i = value
            FunctionToCall()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Or implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)